# Regex matching with "(" in perl

Tags: regex, perl

I have tried the below code

```
my $line = "(int)";
my $pattern = qr(^\(int\));

if ( $line =~ /$pattern/ ) {
    print "line matched";
} else {
    print "line not matched";
}
```

It is not matching.

Can you please help with a pattern which matches this line

Thanks.

Comment: [Your code is working for me in this demo](https://rextester.com/LUB51998).

Comment: Thanks Tim. Online it is working. I have use perl-5.8.3. It is not working for me. Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe earlier versions of perl may have had a bug like this, where if you use `\` to escape a regex metacharacter that is also the quoted construct delimiter, it is treated as the metacharacter, not a literal character.  Try using a different delimiter for your regex, e.g.  `qr/^\(int\)/`.

---

```
$ for v in 10 12 14 16 18 20 22 24 26 ; do
   echo "5.$v"
   "5.${v}t"/bin/perl -le'print qr(^\(int\))'
   echo
done
5.10
(?-xism:^(int))

5.12
(?-xism:^(int))

5.14
(?^:^(int))

5.16
(?^:^(int))

5.18
Useless use of '\'; doesn't escape metacharacter '(' at -e line 1.
(?^:^(int))

5.20
Useless use of '\'; doesn't escape metacharacter '(' at -e line 1.
(?^:^(int))

5.22
(?^:^\(int\))

5.24
(?^:^\(int\))

5.26
(?^:^\(int\))
```

So 5.18 added a warning when you use an escaped delimiter (even if warnings are off), and 5.22 changed the behavior.

(Almost like a deprecation cycle except that the warning warned that you might not have expected the old behavior, not of the coming new behavior, which seems unfortunate.)

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Nope.  Apparently it fails on 5.8.3.  It works for me on 5.22.

Comment: @ysth I tried it. `qr/^\(int\)/` worked fine in 5.8.3. Thanks.

Comment: How many years gap is that?  Quite a lot!  (Perl's releases are documented on [CPAN](https://www.cpan.org/src/README.html).  5.8.3 was released 2004-04-21; 5.8.9 on 2008-12-14; 5.22.0 on 2015-06-01.  So that spans a decade.  Not complaining, just commenting.)